# Script PHP não insere no banco SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

Boa Noite, amigos

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção no banco SQL com o seguinte formulário

`
Descrição

```
                            <label for="password">Valor</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="password" id="valor" name="valor" class="form-control" placeholder="R$ 0,00">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <h2 class="card-inside-title">TIPO</h2>
                            <div class="demo-checkbox">                                
                                <input type="checkbox" id="basic_checkbox_2" class="filled-in" checked />
                                <label for="basic_checkbox_2">Receita</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_21" class="filled-in chk-col-red"  />
                                <label for="md_checkbox_21">Despesa</label>
                            </div>

                            <h2 class="card-inside-title">Data do lançamento</h2>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-line" id="bs_datepicker_container">
                                        <input type="text" id="datalancamento" name="datalancamento" class="form-control" placeholder="Please choose a date...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" class="filled-in">
                            <label for="remember_me">Remember Me</label>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">LOGIN</button>
                        </form>`
```

o Arquivo PHP tem o seguinte código :

`<?php
$serverName = "02262199\SQLEXPRESS"; //nome do servidor
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"controlepessoal", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"11111111");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$datalancamento = $_POST['datalancamento'];

```
$query = "INSERT INTO LANCAMENTOS (DESCRICAO, VALOR, TIPO, DATALANCAMENTO) VALUES ('$descricao', '$valor', '$tipo', '$datalancamento')";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if ($result) {
    //echo 'Dados inseridos com sucesso.';
    header('location: painel.php?url=financeiro');

} else {
    echo 'Erro ao inserir dados: ' . sqlsrv_errors();
}
```

}`

Porem quando clico para enviar o formulario ele chama o arquivo PHP e nada acontece, não insere no banco

Já revisei o código por horas,
-ESTOU USANDO PHP com banco SQL SERVER

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo de como você poderia melhorar o seu código HTML para enviar os dados do formulário para o banco de dados:

```
<form action="processa_cadastro.php" method="post">
    <label for="valor">Valor</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-line">
            <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" class="form-control" placeholder="R$ 0,00">
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="card-inside-title">Tipo</h2>
    <div class="demo-checkbox">                                
        <input type="radio" id="receita" name="tipo" value="receita" class="filled-in" checked>
        <label for="receita">Receita</label>
        <input type="radio" id="despesa" name="tipo" value="despesa" class="filled-in">
        <label for="despesa">Despesa</label>
    </div>

    <h2 class="card-inside-title">Data do lançamento</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-line" id="bs_datepicker_container">
            <input type="date" id="datalancamento" name="datalancamento" class="form-control" placeholder="Selecione a data do lançamento">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Adicionei uma ação para o formulário para que ele envie os dados para o arquivo "processa_cadastro.php" quando o botão é clicado, utilizando o método "post".
Mudei o campo "password" para "text" e adicionei um placeholder para esclarecer o tipo de valor esperado.
Mudei os checkboxes para radios, para que só possa ser selecionado uma opção.
Adicionei valores "receita" e "despesa" para os inputs para que sejam enviados no formulário e facilitar o tratamento no PHP.
Alterei o tipo de input para "date" para selecionar a data de forma mais intuitiva, e o placeholder para esclarecer o tipo de informação esperada
Alterei o texto do botão para "Cadastrar" para indicar claramente a ação que será realizada.

Aqui está um exemplo de como você poderia escrever o código PHP para receber as informações do formulário e inserir no banco de dados:

```
<?php
// Conectando ao banco de dados
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Recebendo os dados do formulário
$valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['valor']);
$tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tipo']);
$datalancamento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['datalancamento']);

// Inserindo os dados no banco de dados
$sql = "INSERT INTO Lancamentos (valor, tipo, datalancamento) VALUES ('$valor', '$tipo', '$datalancamento')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Novo lançamento cadastrado com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Primeiro, é realizada a conexão com o banco de dados.
Em seguida, as informações enviadas pelo formulário são armazenadas nas variáveis $valor, $tipo e $datalancamento.
Por fim, os dados são inseridos na tabela 'Lancamentos' no banco de dados com uma instrução SQL.
Importante: Lembre-se de substituir os valores de $servername, $username, $password e $dbname com os dados corretos do seu servidor e banco de dados. Além disso, certifique-se de que a tabela 'Lancamentos' existe e tem as colunas 'valor', 'tipo' e 'datalancamento'

Eu também recomendo a utilização de prepared statements, pois elas oferecem maior segurança contra ataques de injeção SQL.